# Multiple conditions in if statement javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to filter by multiple fields [dropdowns], but the fields could also be empty. The only way I can think of doing this, is the one shown below, but I was looking for a less bloated way than having to make 20 or so `if`s

`a could have values 1 or 2`

`b could have values 3 or 4 or 5 or 6`

`c could have values 7 or 8 or 9`

`d could have values 10 or 11 or 20`

```
if( a !== '' || b !== '' || c !== '' || d !== ''){
    if((a == 1 || a == 2) && (b == 3 || b == 4 || b == 5 || b == 6) && (c == 7 || c == 8 || c == 9) && (d == 10 || d == 11 || d == 12)){
        // more code here where i use the values of a/b/c/d to get data from an object
    }
}

// a empty
else if( b !== '' || c !== '' || d !== ''){
    if((b == 3 || b == 4 || b == 5 || b == 6) && (c == 7 || c == 8 || c == 9) && (d == 10 || d == 11 || d == 12)){
        // more code here
    }
}

// b empty
else if( a !== '' || c !== '' || d !== ''){
    if((a == 1 || a == 2) && (c == 7 || c == 8 || c == 9) && (d == 10 || d == 11 || d == 12)){
        // more code here
    }
}

// a and b empty
else if( c !== '' || d !== ''){
    if((c == 7 || c == 8 || c == 9) && (d == 10 || d == 11 || d == 12)){
        // more code here
    }
}

and so on ...
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `=` is for value assignment, `==` and `===` are for comparison.

Comment: you can update this "if( a !== '' || b !== '' || c !== '' || d !== '')" to "if( a || b || c || d)"

Comment: How will you use a,b,c,d inside of the if condition?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty I have an object `my_object`, and if `my_object.property1 == a && my_object.property2 == b && ...` I get that item from my object and put it in another object `filtered_object`, which is why I can't have my variables be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array includes() method:

```
var aS = [1,2];
var bS = [3,4,5,6];
var cS = [7,8,9];
var dS = [10,11,20];
if (a || b || c || d) {
    if (aS.includes(a) || bS.includes(b) || cS.includes(c) || dS.includes(d)) {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

The first if will fire if one or more are not empty, and the second will fire if any of the values are what they are supposed to be.

Answer (score -1):

Can we create the common constant like

```
 const aCondition = (a === 1 || a === 2) and so on...
 if( a !== '' || b !== '' || c !== '' || d !== ''){
   if(aCondition && bCondition && cCondition && dCondition){
    // more code here where i use the values of a/b/c/d to get data from an object
  }
 }
```

so in this way you can reuse the conditions and code will look much simpler.